# Each retorna null en relaciones laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

He estado practicando `laravel` y hay algo que no me funciona y no termino de comprender ni revisando la documentación.

Resulta que quiero llamar a los objetos relacionados entre tablas para poder sacar sus otros datos, y cuando lo hago con `find` con un id específico para un objeto funciona, pero cuando lo hago con `each` para todo el listado me devuelve las relaciones como `NULL`.

//Acá me retornar NULL

```
$articles = Article::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);
$articles->each(function($articles){
    $articles->categorie;
    $articles->user;
});
dd($articles);
```

//Pero si lo pruebo así me retorna bien las relaciones

```
$articles = Article::find(2);
$articles->categorie;
$articles->user;    
dd($articles);
```

Comment: Tambien tengo ese problema ... como lo solucionaron? Utilice lo que mencionan pero no me ayuda en nada ...

Comment: Revisa que las relaciones estén bien formadas, en los modelos especifica las llaves foraneas `belongsTo('ubicacion modelo',fk','pk')` , lo especificas tanto para padres como para hijos. 

Si la relación entre modelos está bien realizada, deberás poder acceder con el metodo with a los elementos como me han enseñado en las respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente `each()` no es la opción adecuada en este caso, pues simplemente es un wrapper para iterar, pero no es la forma para obtener las relaciones.

Para eso existe [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), el cual te permite cargar una o varias relaciones al momento de utilizar Eloquent y antes de generar la consulta. La ventaja con respecto al segundo método que muestras en la pregunta es que haces una sola consulta con Eager Loading, mientras con un foreach o llamar las colecciones después sin precargarlas, genera consultas adicionales:

```
$articles = Article::with(['categorie', 'user'])->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);
```

En caso que necesites por algún motivo cargar las relaciones después de haber hecho la primera consulta, la mejor forma es con load():

```
$articles = Article::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);

$articles->load('categorie', 'user');
```

Nota la pequeña diferencia como se deben pasar los parámetros de entrada en ambos métodos.

Answer (score 0):

¿Y si lo haces con un foreach normal?

```
$articles = Article::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);
foreach($articles as $article){
    $article->categorie;
    $article->user;
});
dd($articles);
```

Puede ser también que estes sobrecargando la variable $articles prueba de esta forma:

```
$articles = Article::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);
$articles->each(function($article){
    $article->categorie;
    $article->user;
});
dd($articles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mirate la funcion "with()" que basicamente te ahorrara eso que intentas hacer

```
$articles = Article::with('categorie')->with('user')->orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(5);
```

Te dejo enlace oficial https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading